# Can these sets meet?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $(F_{n})$ is a decreasing sequence of closed set, $B$ is an open ball, all in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. Set $A:=\cap_{n}F_{n} $. Suppose $A$ has empty interior with no isolated points. If the boundary of $B$ is entirely included in $A$, can we conclude that $B\cap A$ is empty?

Answer (score 5):

The Cantor set in $\Bbb R$ is usually constructed as the intersection of a decreasing sequence of closed sets, and it has no isolated points, and empty interior, so we can let $A$ be the Cantor set. Then we have the open ball $B$ centered at $1/2$ with radius $1/2$, which has boundary $\{0,1\}\subseteq A$. However, most of $A$ is contained within $B$, so they do intersect.

Comment: +1. A comment to the OP on this answer versus mine: note that the example I give is connected, but only works in dimension $>1$. This is necessary - there are "few" connected sets in dimension $1$. If you contain two boundary points of the $1$-ball, and are connected, then you contain the entire $1$-ball.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that if $k>1$, a straight line has empty interior. So the set $A$ consisting of the boundary of the open ball of radius $1$ centered at the origin, *together with some "chord" in that sphere*, is a closed set containing the boundary of $B$ which has empty interior and no isolated points; but $A\cap B$ is nonempty (it consists of the "chord," minus the endpoints). And it's not hard to show that this $A$ can be the intersection of a strictly decreasing sequence of closed sets.